# Graphql dotnet v7 can not identify UseGraphql

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, graphql-dotnet

I simply create new dotnet web api core v7 and want to add dotnet graphql v7 too.

this is my `program.cs`

```
using GraphQL;
using Erapi.Graphql.Queries;
using GraphQL.Types;
using Erapi.Graphql.Notes;
using GraphQL.MicrosoftDI;
//using GraphQL.Server;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISchema, NotesSchema>(services => new NotesSchema(new SelfActivatingServiceProvider(services)));
builder.Services.AddGraphQL(options =>
                    options.ConfigureExecution((opt, next) =>
                    {
                        opt.EnableMetrics = true;
                        return next(opt);
                    }).AddSystemTextJson()
                );

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("*")
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

//app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseGraphQL(); <-- error here

await app.RunAsync();
```

the `error`:

> Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'WebApplication' does not contain a definition for
> 'UseGraphQL' and no accessible extension method 'UseGraphQL' accepting
> a first argument of type 'WebApplication' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and this is my packages:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL" Version="7.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.MemoryCache" Version="7.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.MicrosoftDI" Version="7.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.NewtonsoftJson" Version="7.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.SystemTextJson" Version="7.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.17.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

how to solve this? is this a bugs? or I miss something?